# Overriding admin form for a model in django

Tags: python, django, forms

Here's my models.py

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField 

    class Question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        users = User.objects.values_list('id','username')
        authorized = MultiSelectField(choices=users, null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.question_text
```

My problem is that while server is running after user register my choices field are not updating till rerun my server.
I did some research and i found solution for that:
https://mschmitt.org/blog/dynamic-django-form-choice-labels/
http://www.ilian.io/django-forms-choicefield-with-dynamic-values/

I have no idea how to override model in forms + i need to override model in django admin forms. any pointers would be great!
thanks in advance

Comment: This is the second question from you in the past day where the root of the issue has to do with improperly defining related fields. Perhaps you should read up on related fields with the links provided in the answer to your previous question...

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this at all. If you want to store related objects, you should use a proper database relationship.

In this case, a ManyToManyField to User would be appropriate, since a question can have multiple authorized users and presumably a user can be authorized for multiple questions.

Comment: thanks for answet,I tried that , but idk how to handle multiselectionfield then

Comment: I don't understand your question. An m2m is a multi direct field in the admin or a modelform.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman kindly help check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666739/extending-django-oscarapi-api-root-to-custom-api-class Thank you