# Extending django-oscarapi API ROOT to custom API class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

I have a django oscar application and I use django-oscarapi for my custom APIs. Some things are missing from the oscarapi like category and promotions but I have been able to use django-restframework to create the category API but the challenge I am facing now is how to add it to the API-ROOT. This is my code for rendering categories

**customapi serializer class**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'numchild', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'slug')
```

**Views**

```
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer


class CategoryDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

**customapi/urls.py**

```
url(r'^caty/$', CategoryList.as_view(), name='category-list'),
url(r'^caty/(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+(/[\w-]+)*)_(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        CategoryDetail.as_view(), name='category'),
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "add it to API root"? What is API root & why do you want to add the urls there?

Comment: The django oscarapi returns some API response, I now want to add some more.... how I am going to add it to get displayed as other API hyperlink on the API ROOT page e.g `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/`

Comment: Just like any other django url / view? You can give arbitrary patterns to URLs, and AFAIK oscarapi url "names" are without namespace, e.g. `api-products`, so no issues there as well.

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r - You're comments not correct.  Are you using oscarapi?  There is a view in oscarapi that overrides the root view.  Extending that view is the only way I've found to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the root view of `oscarapi`.  There maybe a way to partially override the module, but I was unsuccessful at this.

module to override:
https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/views/root.py

In your project add a file `yourApp/api/views/root.py` and paste in the contents of the source file above.

You can then add end points by adding a tuple to the PUBLIC_APIS or ADMIN_APIS function.