# Modifying oscarapi to show some endpoints as public from admin endpoints

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

What I am trying to achieve is to customize the oscarapi to expose the partner api to be public api instead of just for admin

I have followed the docs on how to customize the api and also did as suggested by Jamie Marshall in
[Extending django-oscarapi API ROOT to custom API class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50666739/extending-django-oscarapi-api-root-to-custom-api-class)

So far I am able to overwrite the root.py file but failing to get oscar see the new urls.py file.

My work so far is as follows

1. I created a api_customization/views/partner.py file
2. I created a api_customization/views/root.py file
3. I tried to extend the urls.py file by creating a api_customization/urls.py file

However, I'm getting the following error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner response = get_response(request)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner return func(*args, **kwds)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch response = self.handle_exception(exc)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception raise exc
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/code/.../forked_apps/api_customization/views/root.py", line 52, in api_root apis = PUBLIC_APIS(request, format)
    File "/code/.../forked_apps/api_customization/views/root.py", line 29, in PUBLIC_APIS ("partners", reverse("partner-list", request=r, format=f)),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py", line 47, in reverse url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/reverse.py", line 60, in _reverse url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
  django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'partner-list' not found. 'partner-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
  [09/Jul/2021 21:18:13] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 500 136185
```

views/partner.py

```
from oscarapi.utils.loading import get_api_class
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
from rest_framework import generics

PartnerSerializer = get_api_class("serializers.product", "PartnerSerializer")
Partner = get_model("partner", "Partner")

class PublicPartnerList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Partner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartnerSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from oscarapi.utils.loading import get_api_class
from oscarapi import urls

PublicPartnerList = get_api_class("views.partner", "PublicPartnerList")

urls.urlpatterns += [
    path("partners1/", PublicPartnerList.as_view(), name="partner-list"),
]

urls.urlpatterns += format_suffix_patterns(urls.urlpatterns)
```

views/root.py

```
import collections

from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


__all__ = ("api_root",)


def PUBLIC_APIS(r, f):
    return [
        # other urls .......
        ("partners", reverse("partner-list", request=r, format=f)),
    ]

# remaining file content ......
```

I need a direction or a hint on how to achieve this
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this and might be helpful form someone

I had to do the same steps done for root.py file to get my app recognise the custom urls.py file

So what I did

1. copy the content of [urls.py](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-api/blob/master/oscarapi/urls.py)
2. modify the file to suit my needs
3. update my app urls.py file to point to the custom urls.py file of the api

```
    //So from this
    path("api/", include("oscarapi.urls")),
    //To this
    path("api/", include("APP_NAME.forked_apps.api_customization.urls")),
```